# Undefined variable when sending data to a view in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have the following problem: I load the main layout (view) of the site in the `renderOutput` method which is written on the parent controller `SiteController.`

```
protected function renderOutput(){
  $menu = $this->getMenu();
  $navigation = view(env('THEME').".navigation")->with('menu',$menu)->render();
  $this->vars = array();
  $this->vars = array_add($this->vars,'navigation', $navigation);

  return view($this->template)->with($this->vars);
}
```

And in the child controller `IndexController` in the `index` method, I call this method. And also to display the section (section) sliders in the index method, I pass the `$sliders` variable to the address of the slider template.

```
public function index(){
    //
    $sliders = view(env('THEME').".slider")->render();
    $this->vars = array();
    $this->vars = array_add($this->vars,'sliders',$sliders); 

    return $this->renderOutput();
}
```

But when I use this variable in the template, I get an error. That is, the `$sliders` variable is not available in the template. Please tell me how to solve the problem. Thank you in advance!

> Undefined variable: sliders (View: C:\Users\User\Downloads\Programs\OSPanel\domains\Corporate\resources\views\pink\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `renderOutput()` you are overwriting `$this->vars` that is why it is undefined.

Use:

```
protected function renderOutput(){
  $menu = $this->getMenu();
  $navigation = view(env('THEME').".navigation")->with('menu',$menu)->render();
  $this->vars = array_add($this->vars,'navigation', $navigation);

  return view($this->template)->with($this->vars);
}
```